# Importing dll into C++ program

Tags: c++, dll, c++-cli

I'm trying to rewrite the following VB code into C++ to import and use a DLL file:

```
    <DllImport("NfcReader.dll", EntryPoint:="CommOpen")> _
Public Function CommOpen(ByRef hCom As IntPtr, ByVal com_port As String) As Short
End Function
```

I tried to use the following code:

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace sensor{ 
[DllImport("NfcReader.dll", EntryPoint = "CommOpen")]
short int CommOpen(intptr_t hCom, std::string com_port);
}
```

But I keep getting error system.accessviolation because apparently my functions parameter can't be a string.
Can somebody help me fix this problem?  I don't know if DllImport() is even the proper function to use in this case?

Comment: Regardless of the possibility that this may work...I don't believe it is good, or even sane, to import libraries from other languages...This is plan C++, you are not on CLI...

Comment: Regardless of the answer I wrote below, questions like "How do I convert this code snippet from one language to another?" are typically not welcome on SO.  They have a very limited scope.  In the future try wording your question so that it has benefit to a wider audience.  Read the FAQ regarding how to ask a question.

Comment: On CLI you wouldn't need to do such thing, as CLI classes work (mostly) across all .NET languages...

Answer (score 0):

The `DllImportAttribute` only imports C-style DLLs into the CLI.

That would mean that NfcReader.dll is a standard C/++ dll and you should be able to use it however one typically uses dlls in C/++.  I've never done C/++ but I would assume `LoadLibrary()` would be a good place to start.

Comment: It does not import the DLL, it imports a function from a DLL. And it includes C++ namescrambling with Microsofts namescrambling algorithm. In C++ CLI you can link against plain C++. As much as I know you can call native functions without any extra declaration. The attribute is just for use within Visual Basic and Visual C#.